# Trouble downloading a sound file with paperclip (routing error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am trying to give my users the ability to download a sound file.  Here are my routes:

```
root 'welcome#index'

get 'sound/:id' => 'sound#download', :as => :download

resources :users, :sounds, :authentications

delete "authentications/:id" => "authentications#destroy"
```

The Sound model is here:

```
class Sound < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # for paperclip
  has_attached_file :sound_file

  # do not create a sound unless a sound file
  # is present
  validates_attachment_presence :sound_file
end
```

I created a download function in my Sound controller:

```
def download
  @sound= Sound.find(params[:id])

  send_file @sound.sound_file.path,
            :filename => @sound.sound_file_file_name,
            :type => @sound.sound_file_content_type,
            :disposition => 'attachment'
end
```

Now when the user presses the download button, the sound file should be downloaded.

```
<% @sounds.each do |sound| %>
  ...some code...
  <%= button_to "Download", download_path(sound.id), method: :get %>
<br>
```

Unfortunately, when the user presses the button, he or she gets this error instead:

No route matches [POST] "/sound/4"

Pretty sure the error is in the routes, but I am not sure how to fix it.  The Paperclip docs  do not deal a lot with downloads.  I have been looking through Stack Overflow and cannot find a solution.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your routes are perfectly all right the problem is with your view code. if you see the routing exception it is doing the post request ideally it should do a get request try changing your button_to to this and give a try

```
<%= button_to "Download", download_path(sound.id), :method => :get %>
```

Comment: I changed the code to match the code above.  Now I am getting the following error: uninitialized constant SoundController.

Comment: My controller file for the sounds model is called sounds_controller.  Can this be the issue?

Comment: yes that is the issue please change the routes to get "sounds/:id" => sounds#download, :as => :download